# Is the text 若承租人是公司，则必须提供法定代表人资料 official and correct?

Tags: writing, formal

I asked a good friend of mine to write the following text in Chinese: if tenant is a company, it should provide the name of the representative.

She translated into: 若承租人是公司，则必须提供法定代表人资料。

Since it's based of a contract, it should be written as officially as possible. But I have a hard time analysing this text.

What does: 若承 and 则必 mean?

How are these related and how to construct a sentence with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text sounds very official and formal

若 (if)

承租人 (tenant)

是 (is)

公司 (company)

则 (then)

必须 (must)

提供 (provide)

法定 (legal)

代表人 (representative)

资料 (information)

> 若承租人是公司，则必须提供法定代表人资料。
>
> If the tenant is a company, then it must provide the information of the legal representative

*I think 法定(legal) is not needed, since the representative is bonded by a legal agreement with the company*

Comment: 法定代表人 as a whole is a legal term.

Comment: That's the reason I didn't omit 法定 in the answer. In layman's term,  代表人 from a  公司 already implied he or she is legally bonded by a contract